# How do I locate an element which is not visible in source?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm using selenium 2, `webdriver.Firefox()`, it's quite frustrating when you have to search for answers everywhere. If anybody could point out a place which provides good/detailed reference, please help me out.

And here's my problem:

For example, sites like `login.live.com` is a heavy user of javascript, and I just simply couldn't locate elements such as the ID or Password input area. Would anybody please shed some light on how to locate these kinds of elements as well?

Comment: There are almost 800 questions tagged `webdriver` here on StackOverflow.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath works for me:

```
//*[text()='Windows Live ID:']/following::input[1]
//*[text()='Password:']/following::input[1]
```

If you are familiar with Firebug, then get [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/). It integrates with Firebug and helps a lot with constructing XPaths.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just found out that FireFox plugin Firebug is a very powerful tool for these.

Comment: I recommend you also XPath Checker - another very useful Firefox plugin.